# How to control Java class diagrams in jDeveloper 12c

Tags: java, jdeveloper, class-diagram, model-associations

Consider the following classes.

```
public class Vector
{
  public Vector()
  {
    super();
  }
}

public class Observation
{
  private Vector vec1;
  private Vector vec2;
  private Vector vec3;
  private Vector vec4;
  private Vector vec5;

  public Observation()
  {
    super();
  }
}
```

Observation and Vector are associated because Observation's members are all Vectors.

If I create a Java class diagram in jDeveloper 12c, I get the following model:

[image: Java class diagram from jDeveloper 12c]

Notice that there is an association edge for each Vector member of Observation. I don't want this! I've figured out how to mitigate some of the problem (it had previously also included the member name at the end of each edge!), but I can't figure out how to get rid of the extra association edges all together. I simply want ONE edge that shows that there is in fact an association.  I have considered hiding all the superfluous edges... but that is labor intensive.  Surely there is an option somewhere to turn this off.  I have yet to find it, though, either on my own or through searching forum posts.  Thank you for your help in advance.